# QGIS won't boot under user but will under admin

Tags: qgis, windows

I have run into an issue where QGIS will not boot under my user profile but will but under the Admin profile.  When I try to open it under my profile, nothing happens.  It was working a couple of days ago. I have had my Admin team look at it and though don't know what is going on. I have deleted and reinstalled QGIS and it still has the same behavior.

I am running QGIS version 3.28.13-Firenze on Windows 10 Enterprise.

Comment: Did you install QGIS or the Admin? What installer did you use? You could try the OSGeo4W installer: https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w

Comment: Re-installs don't provide a new app data folder.  You can rename or delete yours and see if that fixes things.  The folder is typically here in Windows intallations: C:\Users\yourusernamehere\AppData\Roaming\QGIS.  Renaming means you have the current one available with customizations, plugins, etc. in case this doesn't fix things, and you can replace the new one with it.

Comment: I installed as a User with Admin Privelages both with the QGIS Download and OSGEO4W.  I will check the folder to see if that is the issue

Comment: Looks like deleting the AppData folder worked.  Thanks for the help